# Sorting the dataframe by matching multiple columns and conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, match, multiple-columns

The input data:

```
| source_element |   source_text     | source_entity  | target_element | target_text  | target_entity  |
|---------------|-------------------|----------------|---------------|-------------|----------------|
|    vvvvvv      |       ['body']    |      name      |     aaaaa      |     ceo      |      code      |
|    vvvvvv      |       ['body']    |      name      |     bbbbb      |     cap      |      code      |
|    vvvvvv      |  ['body', 'fat']  |      name      |     ccccc      |     fat      |      name      |
|    hhhhhh      | ['man', 'hat']    |      name      |     kkkkk      |     hat      |      name      |
|    kkkkk       |      ['hat']      |      name      |     lllll      |     700      |     price      |
|    kkkkk       |      ['hat']      |      name      |     fffff      |     mud      |      code      |
|    eeeee       |     ['strong']    |      name      |     zzzzz      |     300      |     price      |
|    ssssss      |      ['head']     |      name      |     ddddd      |     zip      |      code      |
|    ssssss      | ['head', 'strong']|      name      |     eeeee      |    strong    |      name      |
|    ssssss      |  ['head', 'part'] |      name      |     uuuuu      |     part     |      name      |
|    uuuuu       |      ['part']     |      name      |     xxxxx      |     190      |     price      |
```

the output:

```
|  source_text   |  source_entity    |  target_text   |  target_entity    |
|-----------------|----------------|----------------|-------------------|
| ['body', 'fat']|       name        |     'ceo'      |       code        |
| ['body', 'fat']|       name        |     'cap'      |       code        |
| ['man', 'hat'] |       name        |     '700'      |      price        |
| ['man', 'hat'] |       name        |     'mud'      |       code        |
| ['head', 'strong'] |    name        |     'zip'      |       code        |
| ['head', 'strong'] |    name        |     '300'      |      price        |
| ['head', 'part'] |      name        |     'zip'      |       code        |
| ['head', 'part'] |      name        |     '190'      |      price        |
```

I need the output that should satisfy these conditions:

1.If source_entity and target_entity are "name", then the source_element or target_element of that particular row matches with source_element of any row in entire dataframe, replace the target_text and text_entity with the matched row of dataframe and remove the rows with source_entity and target_entity are "name".

2.Keep the other dataframe rows which is not effected with above condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

cond = (df['source_entity'] == 'name') & (df['target_entity'] == 'name')
bbb = df[~df.index.isin(df[cond].index)]

def fff(x):
    a = bbb[bbb['source_element'] == df.loc[x, 'source_element']]
    b = bbb[bbb['source_element'] == df.loc[x, 'target_element']]
    if len(a) > 0:
        df.loc[a.index, 'source_text'] = df.loc[x, 'source_text']
        return x
    elif len(b) > 0:
        df.loc[b.index, 'source_text'] = df.loc[x, 'source_text']
        return x


aaa = [fff(i) for i in df[cond].index]
ind = df.index.isin(aaa)

print(df[~ind][['source_text', 'source_entity', 'target_text', 'target_entity']])
```

Output

```
     source_text source_entity target_text target_entity
0    'body  fat'          name       'ceo'          code
1    'body  fat'          name       'cap'          code
4      'man hat'          name       '700'         price
5  'head strong'          name       'zip'          code
```

if you need to reset the indexes:

```
print(df[~ind][['source_text', 'source_entity', 'target_text', 'target_entity']].reset_index(drop=True))
```

**Update**

A completely different approach is used here, in which strings are generated (created).

The 'source_text' column data is turned into a string `df['source_text'].str.join(',')`.

Like last time, we get `bbb` strings that do not have a double 'name'.

But, in the `fff` function, the indexes of matches for 'source_element', 'target_element' are obtained, and if they are found, we get `'source_text'`. Everything is written to the `aaa` list. In `qqq` rows are generated. The source_text column is created on the fly `assign(source_text=i[1])`. The resulting lists are connected by `np.vstack`. The dataframe is created.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['source_text'] = df['source_text'].str.join(',')

cond = (df['source_entity'] == 'name') & (df['target_entity'] == 'name')
bbb = df[~df.index.isin(df[cond].index)]


def fff(x):
    a = bbb[bbb['source_element'] == df.loc[x, 'source_element']]
    b = bbb[bbb['source_element'] == df.loc[x, 'target_element']]
    if len(a) > 0 or len(b) > 0:
        tex = df.loc[x, 'source_text']
        return [list(a.index) + list(b.index), tex]


aaa = [fff(i) for i in df[cond].index]

qqq = np.array(
    [df.loc[i[0], ['source_entity', 'target_text', 'target_entity']].copy().assign(source_text=i[1]).values for i in aaa])

qqq = np.vstack(qqq)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(qqq, columns=['source_entity', 'target_text', 'target_entity', 'source_text'])

df1['source_text'] = df1['source_text'].str.split(',')

print(df1[['source_text', 'source_entity', 'target_text', 'target_entity']])
```

Output

```
   source_text source_entity target_text target_entity
0     body,fat          name         ceo          code
1     body,fat          name         cap          code
2      man,hat          name         700         price
3      man,hat          name         mud          code
4  head,strong          name         zip          code
5  head,strong          name         300         price
6    head,part          name         zip          code
7    head,part          name         190         price
```

If you need to return the lists back:

```
df1['source_text'] = df1['source_text'].str.split(',')
```

Comment: Can You modify the code If I include extar input data:
[('kkkkk'   ,                'hat',              name,          'fffff',   'mud',  code),
('eeeee',  'strong',  name,  'zzzzz',   '300',  price),
('ssssss',  'head', 'part',   name,  'uuuuu',   'part,'  name),('uuuuu',  'part', name,  'xxxxx',   '190',  price)]
Extra output:
[('man', 'hat',   name,  'mud',   code), ('head', 'strong',  name,  '300',   price), ('head', 'part',   name,  'zip' ,  code), ('head', 'part',     name , '190', price)]

Comment: @Anonymous post a table and what you want to get with explanations. 
By the fact that you have given it is not clear what the table and the expected result consist of.

Comment: To quickly understand: what are the differences from the previous version?       And the data in the string is exactly in the list: ['body', 'fat'] or is it a string: 'body', 'fat'?

Comment: It is exactly like list of strings :['body', 'fat'] and one more difference is I added these two rows in input data, ('ssssss', ['head', 'part'], 'name', 'uuuuu', 'part', 'name'), ('uuuuu', ['part'], 'name', 'xxxxx', '190', 'price');. The output differs from previous version a bit. But the conditions remain same!

Comment: ``for idx, row in df[cond].iterrows():
    a = df.loc[(df['source_element'] == row['source_element']) & (df['source_entity'] == 'name')]
    b = df.loc[(df['source_element'] == row['target_element']) & (df['source_entity'] == 'name')]
    source_text = row['source_text']
    if len(a) > 0:
        df.loc[a.index, 'source_text'] = [source_text] * len(a)
    if len(b) > 0:
        df.loc[b.index, 'source_text'] = [source_text] * len(b)
`` I modified the above code like this. But I am missing this row in output: ['head', 'strong']  name  'zip'   code

Comment: With such conditions, you will have to select rows every time. Prior to that, there was a replacement of values and new lines were not created. We need to think about how to do it, but this will be the last time ....

Comment: @Anonymous  made another solution.